# Can this recursion be written more efficiently?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, recursion, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I have a hierarchical organization that is a tree where the node is a child if the parent sponsors the child. It seems I can traverse the tree with this code

```
def get_team(self, person, team):
    firstline = User.query(User.sponsor == person.key).fetch(99999999)
    if firstline:
        for person in firstline:
            team.append(person)
            newdownline = self.downline(person, team)        
    return team
```

Using the above I can get a user's organization just by

`downline=user.get_team(user, [])`

But is there a more efficient way since I have to do this many times for a single request and that much recursion might be ineffecient? Or will the code be fine since it can traverse the tree correctly? In my first version I used three variables and I found I could rearrange the code to only two variables instead of this:

```
def downline(self, person, team, teamlist):
    firstline = User.query(User.sponsor == person.key).fetch(99999999)
    if firstline:
        for person in firstline:
            teamlist.append(person)
            newdownline = self.downline(person, team, teamlist)        
            team.append(newdownline)
    return teamlist
```

I found that the teamlist variable wasn't really needed so I removed it. The way I did it was first with one variable too many:

`people = user.downline(user, [], [])`

Comment: Where's the recursion? Did you mean the iteration over `firstline`?

Comment: newdownline = self.downline(person, team, teamlist

Comment: You can optimize for readability by removing the `person` argument, comparing to `self.key` and calling `person.downline` in the loop. Have you measured how fast the program is? Are you sure recursion is the bottleneck?

Comment: i am confused - what is the actual code and what is the previous version? why don't you use `person.get_team` instead of `self.downline` that is then defined as `downline=user.get_team`?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I can't do person.get_team - that is what I'm trying to implement. The team is connected through the sponsor property where the parent node sponsors the child node and the sponsor property is in the child object so what I'm doing is trying to traverse the entire tree resursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a more efficient way to do it, depending on your computational tradeoffs.

You are currently doing a depth-first traversal of your tree, a perfectly fine approach. You could add some speed by caching results at the expense of some RAM usage, so:

```
if person.id in downline_cache:
      team.append(downline_cache[person.id])
else:
      downline_cache[person.id] = results
      team.append(results)
```

If the tree is fairly small, you could just cache the whole thing upfront, once per thread. That takes more RAM than what you're doing, but is much faster than doing a depth-first traversal every time you care what the results are. A lot depends on your usage patterns and the amount of data you're storing.

If you use a cache, you must make sure you have some way to deal with the underlying data changing, either with timeouts and 'eventually correct' type guarantees, or keeping track of when and how you must wipe the cache, or elements of the cache.